# Display all model data inside html page

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to build a website that has products and categories.

When you are on the page of a product, you can click a button to see a list of all the categories it falls under.
You can click another button, that appears on all pages, to see a list of all the categories overall.

In the html page `see_all_categories`, I wrote a simple block like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content%}

    {{Category.all}}

{% endblock content %}
```

I expect to see a messy printout of all the categories but I don't. It doesn't return an error, but it produces nothing, other than the `base.html`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you maybe mean `Category.objects.all`? also, you still need to send the object in your context (your models aren't automatically accessible from the templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution after many long annoying hours of trying everything. I feel dumb but I want to spare the next guy the massive pain in the two-pack.

This is what I did:

In the Views.py, I changed the view function for this page **FROM** this:

```
def view_all_categories(request):
    context = {'Category' : Category}
    return render(request, 'store/see_all_categories.html', context)
```

**TO** this

```
def view_all_categories(request):
    all_cats = Category.objects.all().order_by('id')
    context = {'all_categories' : all_cats}
    return render(request, 'store/see_all_categories.html', context)
```

and in the page `see_all_categories.html` itself, I changed it (from the question) **TO** this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content%}
    {% for cat in all_categories %}
         <p>{{ cat.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And now it works!!

Answer (score 1):

You want to display a list of the categories. I assume your Category model owns an attribute named "title" which is the representation of your Category.

If you're using Django template engine or Jinja2, you can make a for loop inside your template like this :

```
{% for cat in Category.objects.all %}
<a href="#">{{ cat.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

As a troubleshooting, I'd suggest you didn't pass your Category model to your template, that is not done automatically. You have to add your model to the context before rendering the template.

As mentionned in the comments, here is doc for template rendering with Django templates.
[Django Template Guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle)

To add your model to the context you can follow [this guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context).
I don't intend to help you further because I lack of information and that may vary a LOT according to your settings. (Class Based views ? Function based views ? What kind of template are you using... And so on)

Comment: This syntax is invalid in Django templates (which you can assume OP is using, since he doesn't mention Jinja).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle Are you sure it is invalid ? And by the way it is the exact same syntax in Jinja2. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#loop-filtering

Comment: I was referring to the parentheses.

Comment: How do I add the Category model to my template?

Comment: Edited my answer. Just follow the guide.